# Can't call module method

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm writing a Chef cookbook to deploy and application and create users. It doesn't have an API, and uses an odd hashing method, so I've written a short library module for it. I've included only the `makeSalt()` method below for the sake of brevity.

```
module Foo_packagist
  module Password

    def makeSalt(len=31)
      require 'securerandom'
      return Digest.hexencode(SecureRandom.random_bytes((len*6/8.0).ceil)).to_i(16).to_s(36)[0..len-1]
    end

  end
end
```

The trouble is that in every Chef run I get:

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `makeSalt' for Foo_packagist::Password:Module
```

and debugging in `chef-shell` I get:

```
chef (12.4.0)> puts ::Foo_packagist::Password.instance_methods()
makeSalt
encodePassword

chef (12.4.0)> puts ::Foo_packagist::Password.makeSalt()
NoMethodError: undefined method `makeSalt' for Foo_packagist::Password:Module

chef (12.4.0)> puts ::Foo_packagist::Password::makeSalt()
NoMethodError: undefined method `makeSalt' for Foo_packagist::Password:Module
```

What is the *right* way to call this method?

Comment: Your `require` should be at the top of the file, not jammed inside a method.

Comment: That is a pattern we recommend for Chef where some gems might not be available at library load time. `securerandom` is in the stdlib, but it's easier to recommend it as a blanket pattern than explain what is and is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ->

```
module Foo_packagist
  module Password

    def self.makeSalt(len=31)
      require 'securerandom'
      return Digest.hexencode(SecureRandom.random_bytes((len*6/8.0).ceil)).to_i(16).to_s(36)[0..len-1]
    end
  end
end
```

Then to call it would be this->

```
Foo_packagist::Password.makeSalt()
```

Comment: The leading `::` is only necessary if you have a namespace conflict.

Answer (score 2):

Change that to `def self.makeSalt`. That's the Ruby syntax for a module-level method.

Comment: You can also add `extend self` at the end to roll them all in that way.